# Restoring an Odoo Database with Python3 and xmlrpc failing

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, xmlrpclib

I am writing a python script to backup and restore an Odoo database (copy, really).

My code to make the backup is as follows:

```
def download_db() :
    conn = ServerProxy(url + '/xmlrpc/db')
    print ('Dumping database...')

    with open(backup_zip_name, 'wb') as backup_file:
        decode = base64.b64decode(conn.dump(master_password, db_to_copy, 'zip'))
        backup_file.write(decode)
```

This seems to work fine and I can successfully restore the generated backup file manually using the odoo web database manager interface.

However when I try to restore that backup via the script:

```
def restore_db() :
    with open(backup_zip_name, 'rb') as backup_file:
        serv = ServerProxy(url + '/xmlrpc/db')
        print('Creating database ' + new_db_name + ' from ' + backup_zip_name)
        
        serv.restore(master_password, new_db_name, base64.b64encode(backup_file.read()))
        print('done')
```

I get the following error:

> Creating database db_copy from ./backup/backup.zip Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/usr/bin/anonymisation/odoo-database-copy.py", line 97, in 
> restore_db()   File "/usr/bin/anonymisation/odoo-database-copy.py", line 40, in restore_db
> serv.restore(master_password, new_db_name, encode)   File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line
> 1112, in **call**
> return self.__send(self.__name, args)   File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line
> 1452, in __request
> verbose=self.__verbose   File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line
> 1154, in request
> return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)   File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py",
> line 1170, in single_request
> return self.parse_response(resp)   File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line
> 1342, in parse_response
> return u.close()   File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line
> 656, in close
> raise Fault(**self._stack[0]) xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault object of type 'Binary' has no len(): 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n
> File
> "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odoo-12.0.post20181107-py3.6.egg/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py",
> line 54, in xmlrpc_1\n    response = self._xmlrpc(service)\n  File
> "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odoo-12.0.post20181107-py3.6.egg/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py",
> line 43, in _xmlrpc\n    result = dispatch_rpc(service, method,
> params)\n  File
> "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odoo-12.0.post20181107-py3.6.egg/odoo/http.py",
> line 120, in dispatch_rpc\n    result = dispatch(method, params)\n
> File
> "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odoo-12.0.post20181107-py3.6.egg/odoo/service/db.py",
> line 448, in dispatch\n    return gexp_method_name\n  File
> "", line 2, in exp_restore\n  File
> "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odoo-12.0.post20181107-py3.6.egg/odoo/service/db.py",
> line 40, in if_db_mgt_enabled\n    return method(self, *args,
> **kwargs)\n  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odoo-12.0.post20181107-py3.6.egg/odoo/service/db.py",
> line 248, in exp_restore\n    for chunk in chunks(data):\n  File
> "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odoo-12.0.post20181107-py3.6.egg/odoo/service/db.py",
> line 244, in chunks\n    for i in range(0, len(d), n):\nTypeError:
> object of type 'Binary' has no len()\n'>

I am running the script using python 3.6. Any ideas how to fix this please?

ETA: They both work fine on python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base64.b64encode` return a [string](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) in python2.7 and [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) in Python3.6.

Try to pass a string instead of bytes to the `restore` function:

```
base64.b64encode(backup_file.read()).decode()
```